# Print custom symbol when textField is html markup

Tags: html, jasper-reports, textfield

I'm trying to print string `"<"` in jasper report text field with html markup, but it not showing. Here's my code for the sample:

```
CONCATENATE("<", $F{ComponentName}.trim(), "> - ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `markup="html"` on the `textField` and you want to output `<` and `>` you need to replace them exactly the same as any other [html document](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

```
< with &lt;
> with &gt;
```

Example

```
CONCATENATE("&lt;", $F{ComponentName}.trim(), "&gt; - ")
```